# Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_27 was killed

Tags: android, android-studio

Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_27 was killed.
I tried all possible ways .still there is this error,I tried stackoverflow answers,watched youtube .also tried the ways told in youtube still its giving me an error.Guys plz somebody help me .

Comment: I also have trouble with the amulators : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65127293/the-emulator-process-for-avd-xx-was-killed-resetting-for-cold-boot-emulation-en and also tried a lot of stuff.. Could you solve your issue?

Comment: No,still it is not soved.Finally I connected my phone with android